# MYSQL Query with "case when" statement and keeping first row unique and a full list of places

Tags: mysql

Sorry if I do something wrong, this is my first post.  Love the website though.

Need to create a result that has a list of organizations on one column, create a column for each piece of equipment and whether or not it is up or down for each organization.
I need a complete list of places, then create the case when statements showing it up, down or doesnt exist (null).

This doesnt seem to come out right... argh!

Its OK to laugh at this if I am completely wrong and constructive criticism is appreciated.

TABLES:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `support`.`orgs` (
  `idorgs` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 301 ,
  `orgs` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
  `fullname` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idorgs`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idorgs_UNIQUE` (`idorgs` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `orgs_UNIQUE` (`orgs` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB

 CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `avsupport`.`org_comp` (
  `id_org_comp` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `idorgs` INT NOT NULL ,
  `idsys` INT NOT NULL ,
  `updown` TINYINT NULL ,
  `location` VARCHAR(25) NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_org_comp`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_org_comp_UNIQUE` (`id_org_comp` ASC) ,
  INDEX `idorgs_idx` (`idorgs` ASC) ,
  INDEX `idsystems_idx` (`idsys` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `idorgs`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idorgs` )
    REFERENCES `avsupport`.`orgs` (`idorgs` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idsystems`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idsys` )
    REFERENCES `avsupport`.`system` (`idsystems` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `support`.`system` (
  `idsystems` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 101 ,
  `systems` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsystems`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idsystems_UNIQUE` (`idsystems` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `systems_UNIQUE` (`systems` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT c.orgs, 
CASE when updown=1 and idsys = 201 then 5 when updown=0 then 0 end as 'xbox',
Case when updown=1 and idsys = 202 then 10 when updown=0 then 0 end as 'TVs',
Case when updown=1 and idsys = 203 then 10  when updown=0 then 0 end as 'DVD Players',
Case when updown=1 and idsys = 205 then .25 when updown=0 then 0 end as 'CD Players'
from org_comp a, system b, orgs c where a.idsys = b.idsystems and c.idorgs = a.idorgs 
group by orgs;
```

Comment: Can you give a couple of rows from each table please? I think I see the problem but want to confirm.